# Research shows nothing, not even "No Result"

Tags: catalogsearch, search

When I use the search engine on my site, it will return me anything. Not even a page "no results".

The site loads and stays on the page where it was.

I tried to reindex and purge cache it does not change anything.
I already tried to replace the catalogsearch.xml too...

You can see it here : http://bit.ly/1jBwpWf

And this system.log :

> 2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: getDashboardUrl  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 42
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Non-static method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 76
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Non-static method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 76
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Non-static method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 76
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Non-static method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 76
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _productNameStripped  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 107
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _product  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 113
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 113 and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _product  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 114
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 114 and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _product  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 113
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 113 and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _product  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 114
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 114 and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _productNameStripped  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 107
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _product  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 113
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 113 and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _product  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 114
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/home.phtml on line 114 and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
>   2014-02-18T14:21:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: getDashboardUrl  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 42
>   2014-02-18T14:21:34+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: getDashboardUrl  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 42
>   2014-02-18T14:21:34+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: getDashboardUrl  in /app/design/frontend/topper/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 42

Have you any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Errors in system.log, exception.log apache logs?

Comment: ow man...there is something very very wrong with the theme you are using (topper). I seams developed with error reporting off and nobody bothered to test it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Solutions

your  type no name element.

`<input type="text" placeholder="Recherche" class="text">`

`<input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="text" placeholder="Recherche">`

Make it Like this way and try again.